R unmarked package: Incorrect number of rows in obsCovs data frame
I'm relatively new to R and expecially to the unmarked package. I'm trying to run a single-season occupancy analysis and I'm basically stuck at the beginning. I can't really understand why.
My data
library(tibble)
library(unmarked)
Newtdata <- tibble(`BASIC DATA` = c("DataID", "1", "2", "3", "4",  "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15",  "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26",  "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37",  "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48",  "49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58"),
                   ...2 = c("OriginalDataID", "1", "2", "4", "6", "7", "7",      "8", "8", "9", "11", "12", "14", "38", "15", "16", "18",      "19", "25", "27", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35",      "36", "37", "50", "51", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44",      "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "52", "53", "57", "64", "65",      "66", "79", "80", "81", "88", "93", "94", "95", "101", "103",      "105", "106"),
                   ...3 = c("WP", "2", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3",      "3", "3", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "5", "5", "5", "6", "6",      "6", "7", "7", "7", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "9", "9", "9",      "6", "6", "6", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "3", "4", "4",      "4", "4", "5", "5", "5", "7", "7", "7", "8", "8", "8", "8",      "4", "9", "9", "9"),
                   ...4 = c("Survey", "1", "1", "1", "1",      "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1",      "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1",      "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2",      "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2",      "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2"),
                   ...5 = c("Julian day", "98",      "98", "99", "99", "100", "100", "100", "100", "101", "101",      "101", "101", "112", "102", "102", "102", "103", "104", "104",      "105", "105", "105", "107", "107", "107", "107", "107", "111",      "118", "118", "112", "112", "112", "115", "115", "115", "115",      "115", "117", "117", "117", "118", "119", "119", "120", "120",      "120", "123", "123", "124", "125", "126", "126", "126", "128",      "131", "131", "131"),
                   `POND DATA` = c("Pond", "1", "2", "3",      "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14",      "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24",      "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "17", "18", "19", "2",      "31", "4", "8", "7", "6", "5", "9", "10", "11", "12", "15",      "14", "16", "21", "20", "22", "23", "26", "32", "27", "13",      "29", "30", "28"),
                   ...7 = c("Gewässer Typ", "BüffelOverg",      "BüffelOverg", "BüffelOverg", "Artificial", "Natural",      "BüffelOverg", "BüffelOverg", "Büffel", "NaturalStream",      "NaturalStream", "NaturalBüffel", "Natural", "Artificial",      "Flooded", "GrabenFlooded", "NaturalStream", "NaturalStream",      "Natural", "Tränke", "Artificial", "Flooded", "Artificial",      "Büffel", "Natural", "NaturalBüffel", "Büffel", "Büffel",      "NaturalBüffel", "Natural", "NaturalBüffel", "NaturalStream",      "Natural", "Tränke", "BüffelOverg", "BüffelOverg", "Artificial",      "Büffel", "BüffelOverg", "BüffelOverg", "Natural", "Natural",      "BüffelOverg", "NaturalBüffel", "Natural", "GrabenFlooded",      "Flooded", "NaturalStream", "Flooded", "Artificial", "Artificial",      "Büffel", "Büffel", "Büffel", "Büffel", "Artificial",      "Natural", "NaturalBüffel", "NaturalBüffel"),
                   ...8 = c("Longitud",      "302127", "302118", "302169", "302491", "301270", "301191",      "300423", "300312", "349762", "349747", "349690", "349131",      "349405", "359034", "358290", "358353", "330880", "330107",      "330225", "341994", "342026", "342166", "362626", "362836",      "362865", "362946", "362981", "377907", "379119", "377809",      "330883", "330111", "330220", "302120", "302104", "302491",      "300309", "300423", "301193", "301279", "349764", "349763",      "3499686", "349128", "358282", "359041", "358358", "342026",      "341997", "342172", "362634", "362958", "362879", "362969",      "349407", "379119", "377806", "377891"),
                   ...9 = c("Latitud",      "5092494", "5092491", "5092591", "5092446", "5080893", "5080904",      "5081256", "5081306", "5123415", "5123762", "5123840", "5123719",      "5123665", "5109048", "5109554", "5109197", "5134272", "5134250",      "5134332", "5085805", "5085861", "5085601", "5096887", "5097251",      "5097501", "5097343", "5097605", "5110035", "5109662", "5109625",      "5134277", "5134251", "5134331", "5092490", "5092491", "5092446",      "5081308", "5081261", "5080900", "5080894", "5123414", "5123750",      "5123838", "5123723", "5109556", "5109081", "5109200", "5085854",      "5085800", "5085579", "5096879", "5097361", "5097508", "5097609",      "5123662", "5109662", "5109625", "5110034"),
                   ...10 = c("Observation",      NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,      NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,      NA, NA, NA, NA, "Substitut of Pond 1", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,      NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Substitut of Pond 25",      NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
                   OCCURRENCE = c("L. vulgaris", "0", "0",      "0", "1", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "1", "1", "1", "0", "0",      "1", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "1", "1", "0",      "1", "1", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0",      "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "1", "1", "0", "0", "0"),
                   ...12 = c("T. cristatus",      "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "1", "1", "0",      "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0",      "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1",      "0", "0", "1", "1", "0", "1", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0",      "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"),
                   `WOODPASTURE LEVEL DATA` = c("Exposition",      "0.5", "34", "0.33", "0.38", "189", "75", "53", "80", "327",      "335", "354", "347", "342", "318", "166", NA, "339", "305",      "344", "15", "36", "66", "29", "353", "324", "350", "358",      "306", "296", "330", "10", "289", "2", "24", "32", "58",      "106", "81", "90", "106", "340", "338", "16", "66", "135",      "308", "215", "3", "337", "56", "6", "265", "337", "358",      "290", "328", "3", "339"),
                   ...14 = c("Cattle", "1", "1",      "1", "1", "1;2", "2", "2", "2", "1;3", "2", "2;3", "2;3",      "1,3,4", "2;3", "2;3", "3", "1", "1", "1", "1;2;3", "1;3",      "1;3", "1;2;3", "1;2;3", "1;2;3", "1;2;3", "1;2;3", "3",      "1;2;3", "1;2;3", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1;2;3",      "1;2;3", "1;2;3", "1;2;3", "1", "1;2;3", "1;2;3", "1;2;3",      "2", "1;3", "1;3", "1;3", "1;3", "1;2;3", "1;2;3", "1;2;3",      "1;2;3", "1;2;3", "1;3, 4;5", "2;3; 5", "2;3;5", "2;3;5"),
                   ...15 = c("Grazing", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0",      "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0",      "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "1", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0",      "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0",      "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "1", "0", "0",      "0", "1"),
                    `ABIOTIC CONDITIONS` = c("Weather", "Sunny", "Sunny",      "Sunny", "Sunny", "Sunny", "Sunny", "Sunny", "Sunny", "Sunny",      "Sunny", "Sunny", "Sunny", "SunnyWindy", "Sunny", "Sunny",      "Sunny", "Sunny", "Sunny", "Sunny", "Sunny", "Sunny", "Sunny",      "Sunny", "Sunny", "Sunny", "Sunny", "Sunny", "PartCloudy",      "Cloudy", "Sunny", "Sunny", "Sunny", "Sunny", "Sunny", "Sunny",      "Sunny", "Sunny", "Sunny", "PartCloudy", "PartCloudy", "Sunny",      "Sunny", "Sunny", "Sunny", "Sunny", "Sunny", "Sunny", "Sunny",      "Sunny", "Cloudy", "Sunny", "Sunny", "Sunny", "Sunny", "Sunny",      "PartCloudy", "PartCloudy", "PartCloudy"),
                    ...17 = c("AvgGroundT",      "15.3", "13.75", "16.6", "17.9",      "14.06", "21.2", "23.4", "23.4",      "21.82", "24.063", "20.65002",      "14.53", "8.9982", "22.364",      "19.25", "20.32", "21.566", "24.82",      "21.8", "24.66", "20.13", "18.996",      "23.895", "22.58332", "26.668",      "23.16", "23.42", "17.469",      "17.797", "20.94", "19.92",      "15.367", "16.7", "16.21", "18.85001",      "18.7", "18.969", "15.13", "16.92",      "16.2", "14.217", "17.42", "16.563",      "15.9", "13.42", "15.95001", "15.4",      "17.94", "23.364", "25.85", "21.5",      "19", "23.44", "26.969", "22.566",      "18.32", "19.098", "16.05"     ),
                    ...18 = c("AvgWaterT", "18.848", "16.598",      "12.568", "14.65", "13.867",      "16.65002", "27.266", "24.395",      "24.24", "22.42", "20.08336",      "19.766", "9.7989", "17.867",      "22.38329", "22.51", "21.797",      "25.2", "16.82", "15.9", "26.864",      "18.74", "23.32", "25.16",      "25.598", "24.168", "24.71",      "18.668", "22.8", "22.566", "17.3",      "22.01", "15.73", "17.516",      "18.867", "19.598", "17.32",      "20.168", "15.568", "13.467",      "19.66", "17.266", "11.967",      "19.969", "19.7", "20.01", "14.766",      "20.8", "14.666", "15.63", "24",      "21.2", "29.098", "28.51", "15.568",      "27", "22.92", "21.469"),
                    ...19 = c("HumidityMin",      NA, NA, NA, NA, "41", "28.89", "32.65", "26.66", "15.91",      "31.58", NA, "38.89", "38.84003", "30.76", "20.27",      "27.3", "31.9", "28.45", "33.36", "26.22", "25.39", "31.32",      "27.75", "17.07", "23.38", "22.06", "26.64", "32.02003",      "40.227", "35.67", "26.12", "21.44", "18.01002",      "52.43", "40.43", "39.32", "48.82", "51.11", "43.22", "20.34",      "37.64", "28.83", "37.46", "15.63", "27.61", "31.56", "38.17",      "36.73", "30.77", "39.94", NA, "38.82", "32.27003",      "26.32", "44.82", "25.17", "27.91", "30.75"),
                    ...20 = c("HumidityMax",      NA, NA, NA, NA, "42.49", "31.23", "35.95003", "31.94",      "20.26002", "33.85", NA, "40.797",      "93.35", "37.547", "23.38", "35.09003",      "37", "32.367", "37.22", "28.75", "27.85", "33.99",      "33.04", "22.09", "28.11", "26.7", "33.09003",      "38.21", "45.71", "41.55", "30.66", "24.21", "19.57", "57.47",      "45.82", "49.66", "52.08", "53.5", "52.02", "27.53", "45.46",      "32.03", "41.66", "20.76", "30.16", "35.477",      "45.64", "42.8", "32.49", "46.12", NA, "45.17", "37.657",      "30.42", "48.88", "27.92", "32.89", "34"),
                    ...21 = c("AvgWaterDepth(m)",      "8.56E-2", "0.11166", "0.08", "0.2984",      "0.18", "0.23669", "0.17667", "5.2999E-2",      "8.6656E-2", "0.2681", "0.2132",      "0.24", "0.45", "5.33E-2", "0.11", "4.6669E-2",      "0.38", "0.03", "0.283", "0.8377",      "6.325E-2", "0.5232", "0.141",      "0.105", "0.13", "0.1134", "0.17", "0.15665",      "0.06", "0.09", "0.40662", "0.08", "0.2631",      "9.51E-2", "0.1033", "0.38", "5.33E-2",      "0.3236", "0.36664", "0.1933",      "0.125", "0.28668", "0.24167", "0.21667",      "8.343E-2", "5.6671E-2", "3.6667E-2",      "5.33E-2", "0.53663", "0.64", "7.334E-2",      "0.16", "7.334E-2", "0.1633", "0.51",      "7.334E-2", "7.07E-2", "0.12"),
                    `POND GEOMETRY` = c("Pond area (m²)", "15.16248",      "9.42", "20.43649", "6.44", "9.210328",      "13.065", "10.56", "10.199", "92.71", "161.477",      "21.82503", "20.16", "10.199", "1.41",      "18.195", "10.353", "15.21", "0.554", "4.625701",      "14.28", "8.25", "15.3", "18.7209", "4.5449",      "8.19", "141", "48.09747", "6.24", "143.26731",      "21.295", "12.3354", "1.2236", "4.625701",      "32.61624", "23.96544", "9.244797",      "11.61759", "86.43", "22.263", "11.56548",      "102.4", "158.3583", "70.60595", "16.6567",      "9.179393", "2.1461", "3.133",      "1.75", "11.7478", "19.27261", "1.3", "63.999066671",      "21.11401", "46.94689", "10.4", "36.19109",      "6.1875", "4.83"),
                   ...23 = c("Pond size (m³)", "1.2888124999",      "1.051901", "1.634919", "1.921269",      "1.657859", "3.092054", "1.865601",      "0.54057", "8.034859", "43.329661667",      "4.656006", "4.8384", "4.59", "7.4673E-2",      "2.001452", "0.4831401", "5.779807",      "1.651E-2", "1.2951962", "11.95712",      "0.52246", "8.0067", "2.6209263",      "0.4772245", "1.0647", "15.98", "8.1765749997",      "0.97751", "8.5960381", "1.916639",      "5.0163959994", "9.788803E-2", "1.218100",      "3.0985421668", "2.4764312", "3.5130239997",      "0.619605323", "27.94576", "8.163464",      "2.235994", "12.8", "45.396074664", "17.06311",      "3.608954", "0.7649502", "0.121618",      "0.114889", "9.324E-2", "6.3046526658",      "12.334464001", "9.539E-2", "10.239850667",      "1.54836", "7.6679936668", "5.304003", "2.6540141",      "0.4331254", "0.5796"),
                    `POND BIOTIC PARAMETERS` = c("Herbs<30cm",      "52.5", "52.5", "55", "46", "48", "35", "51", "53", "25.5",      "25", "52.5", "54", "37", "60", "48.5", "61", "65", "75",      "12", "7", "25", "40", "50", "46", "38", "55", "25", "55",      "27", "51", "61", "66", "12", "69.5", "60.5", "25", "44",      "50", "53", "48", "39", "47", "38.5", "65", "50", "40", "62",      "40", "6", "12", "10", "40", "35", "8", "41", "20", "65",      "40"),
                    ...25 = c("Herbs40-80cm", "29", "10", "15", "15",      "0", "20", "6", "1", "8.5", "5", "5.5", "1", "3", "20", "15",      "0", "1", "7", "2", "29", "0", "0", "2", "26.5", "12", "0",      "0", "0", "0", "3", "1", "8", "2", "8", "6", "7", "1", "4",      "7", "0", "6", "0", "5.5", "2", "25", "48", "4", "1", "1",      "1", "0", "0", "1", "0", "2", "0", "2", "0"),
                    ...26 = c("Herbs>90cm",      "1", "0", "0.5", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "5", "0", "1.5",      NA, "0", "3", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0",      "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0",      "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "3", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0",      "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), ...27 = c("Woody<2m",      "0", "0", "0", "3", "2", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "2.5",      "0", "0", "0", "2", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0",      "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "3", "0", "0", "0",      "0", "0", "0", "0", "2", "0", "2", "8.5", "0", "0", "0",      "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"     ),
                    ...28 = c("Woody>2m", "0", "0", "0", "0", "3", "0", "0",      "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "7.5", "0", "0", "0",      "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0",      "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "3", "0", "0",      "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0",      "0", "0", "0", "0"),
                    ...29 = c("Dry_leaves", "0", "0", "0",      "0", "0", "0", "0", "7", "0", "0", "1", "2", "15", "1", "5",      "2", "0", "0", "0", "2", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "1", "0",      "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0.5", "0", "0", "5", "0",      "0", "0", "0.5", "1", "0.5", "0", "5", "0", "1", "0", "0",      "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "20", "0", "1", "0"),
                   ...30 = c("Rock_trunks",      "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "2.5", "0", "1.5",      "0", "5", "0", "0.5", "0", "0", "0", "1", "3", "0", "0",      "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0",      "0", "4", "0", "0", "0", "0", "4.5", "0", "0", "1", "0",      "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "3", "0", "0",      "0"),
                   ...31 = c("Bare soil", "0", "0", "2", "10", "7", "5",      "3", "9", "1", "0", "5.5", "3", "5", "8", "4", "12", "3",      "13", "70", "27", "35", "22", "7", "7.5", "15", "17", "35",      "15", "13", "6", "5", "12", "70", "2.5", "1.5", "34", "6",      "2", "5", "7", "1.5", "0", "2", "17", "1", "6", "20", "52",      "72", "42", "85", "28", "18", "37", "7", "19", "10", "30"     ),
                   ...32 = c("Herbs<30cm", "1.5", "3.5", "0.5", "3", "0",      "7", "12", "15", "12.5", "0", "1", "1", "0", "1", "5", "4",      "6", "1", "5", "0", "3", "13", "4", "1.5", "1", "3", "0",      "15", "20", "10", "6", "1", "5", "7.5", "4.5", "3", "20",      "10", "2", "0", "3", "1", "0.5", "1", "2", "0", "5", "0",      "0", "12", "0", "2", "5", "1", "1", "4", "9", "2"),
                   ...33 = c("Herbs40-80cm",      "3", "16", "5.5", "0", "0", "5", "0", "0", "2", "10", "5.5",      "3", "0", "0", "0.5", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "5",      "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "4",      "6.5", "1", "0", "0", "10", "0", "0", "10", "7.5", "1", "5",      "0", "0", "0", "0", "2", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0",      "0"),
                   ...34 = c("Herbs>90cm", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0",      "0", "0", "2", "0", "0", "15", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0",      "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0",      "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0",      "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0",      "0", "0", "0", NA), ...35 = c("Rock_trunks", "0", "0", "0",      "2", "2", "0", "0", "0", "10", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0",      "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0",      "0", "0", "0", "2", "0", "0", "0", "0", "5", "0", "0", "0",      "2", "13", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0",      "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"),
                   ...36 = c("Floating",      "3.5", "2.5", "1.5", "10", "3", "7", "1", "15", "26.5", "28",      "3", "5", "15", "1", "3.5", "1", "2", "0", "1", "1", "1",      "0", "1", "3.5", "12", "3", "0", "5", "0", "0", "0", "0",      "1", "3.5", "13.5", "5", "0", "1", "3", "3", "38.5", "2",      "2", "3", "2", "0", "0", "0", "1", "3", "0", "0", "0", "0",      "12", "2", "1", "0"),
                   ...37 = c("Submerged", "1", "4.5",      "3.5", "0", "5", "7", "1", "0", "0", "38", "15.5", "8", "10",      "1", "10.5", "1", "4", "2", "0", "0", "0", "20", "1", "12",      "5", "0", "0", "15", "0", "7", "3", "1", "0", "7.5", "2",      "1", "24", "0", "20", "5", "20", "27", "19", "4", "0", "0",      "1", "0", "0", "6", "0", "0", "0", "0", "26", "0", "0", "0"     ),
                   ...38 = c("water", "8.5", "11", "16.5", "10", "30", "18",      "26", "0", "4.5", "22", "18.5", "16", "15", "5", "5.5", "19",      "17", "2", "9", "29", "36", "0", "34", "3", "16", "20", "40",      "10", "40", "23", "22", "8", "9", "0", "11.5", "15", "0",      "33", "0", "30", "2", "10", "17.5", "7", "10", "6", "6",      "7", "20", "25", "5", "30", "40", "54", "0", "55", "12",      "28")
                   )

My code
y<-Newtdata[11:12]
siteCovs<-Newtdata[1:10, 14:15]
obsCovs<-Newtdata[16:38]

umf<-unmarkedFrameOccu(y = y, siteCovs = siteCovs, obsCovs = obsCovs)

I get this error:
Error: Incorrect number of rows in obsCovs data frame
I really can't figure out what it means. The number of rows for the columns I called obsCovs is the same as the rest of the table, I tried shrinking them or putting less columns but I keep getting the same error! There's probably an easy solution but I couldn't find anything around the internet for it. Thank you in advance for reading this far :)
UPDATE!
I've tried, unsucessfully, to split up my data into 3 sheets as follows:
SiteCovariatesDF<-as.data.frame(SiteCovariates)
ObservationCovariatesDF<-as.data.frame(ObservationCovariates)
OccurenceMatrix<-as.matrix(Occurrence)

y<-Occurrence
siteCovs<-SiteCovariatesDF
obsCovs<-ObservationCovariatesDF

I still get the same error.

I've never used the unmarked package but I hope this can help.
Part of the issue is that the column headers are in the first row of data - the very first row of the file just contains some meta-titles. I recommend addressing this when you first import the file, for example using readr::read_csv("filename.csv", skip = 1) which would skip the first row. You should end up with a data.frame in this format:



DataID
OriginalDataID
WP
...




1
1
2
...


...
...
...
...



If you run help(unmarkedFrameOccu), the documentation will tell you that if obsCovs is a data.frame (like in your case), it should have RxJ number of rows, where R are the rows of y (sites) and J are the columns of y (sampling periods per site). Your y has 2 columns and 58 rows, so the package is expecting obsCovs to have 116 rows.
So this might either be an issue with the way your data is shaped, or with the way you're using the function.
Side note
Indexing columns by column number (y<-Newtdata[11:12]) is not a good idea: if the underlying data changes, the code will silently break. Also, it's not very easy to read. I recommend insted explicitly using the column names:
library(dplyr)
y <- Newtdata |> select(`L. vulgaris`, `T. cristatus`)

